# How to use combobox text in update query

Tags: c#

Please tell me how to take a combobox text as a column name.

Here is my code :

```
string query = "update teacher set '"+comboBox1.Text+"' = '" + textBox2.Text + "' where teacherid='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to use text of combobox as a set column name in update query it gives error

Comment: comboBox1.selecteditem to be get the text.

Comment: Please Enter The values First Like Hot Code Its with some values and check weather its working or not ..

Comment: If it's working Then Check with ComboBox is contain Value or not Then you will come to know where is the Issue

Comment: You should **never** construct SQL queries from raw user input. Right now you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Imagine, what will happen if `textBox1.Text` will contain `42'; DROP TABLE teacher; --` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
string query = "update teacher set '"+comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(+"' = '" + textBox2.Text + "' where teacherid='" + textBox1.Text + "'"; 

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
comboBox1.selectedItem.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following code.

```
string abc = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(abc);
```

So your code should like this:

```
string query = "update teacher set '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' = '" + textBox2.Text + "' where teacherid='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Also you could look into following DOCS article for more info on Combobox item selection

[ComboBox.SelectedItem Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002600&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

```
    JButton btnNewButton_13 = new JButton("Update");
    btnNewButton_13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //////////////////
            
            try {
                if(textField_4.getText().equals("")||textField_1.getText().equals("")||textField_2.getText().equals("")||comboBoxRoomType.getSelectedItem().equals("")||textField_3.getText().equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill the form and check the details");
                }else {
                Connection con = DBConnection.connect();
                
                String query="Update Locations set RoomName='"+textField_2.getText()+"',BuildingName='"+textField_1.getText()+"' ,RoomType='"+comboBoxRoomType.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'  where LID='"+textField_4.getText()+"' ";
                PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Updated");
                
                
                pst.close();
                }
                
            }
            catch(Exception q) {
                q.printStackTrace();
            }
```